# .net C# generic way to manage IsDirty functionality with class that has hundreds of properties

Tags: c#, .net, generics, properties

I have a complex class with at least 100 properties.  I want to track if any properties have been changed since the class was loaded with data (initialized) so I've coded the following to manage this.  I also don't want to set the IsDirty flag if the value being passed in is the same as the current value of the property.  When the class is instantiated, the IsDirty flag is set to false and while data is being loaded into the class, the IsInitializing flag will be set to true.

```
private T SetPropertyValue<T>(T property, T value)
{
if  (!property.Equals(value))
{
// If values are different, return the new value and
// if the IsInitializing flag is false, then set the dirty flag for the class.
if (!IsInitializing)
IsDirty = true;
return value;
}
// If the current value of the property and the value passed in are the same,
// return the current value of the property.
return property;
}

private DateTimeOffset? _actualProjectCompletionDate;

public DateTimeOffset? ActualProjectCompletionDate
{
get
    {
        return _actualProjectCompletionDate;
    }
set
    {
        _actualProjectCompletionDate = SetPropertyValue(_actualProjectCompletionDate, value);
    }
}
```

I'd like to avoid having to specify the actual private variable twice in the set method, but when I tried to use a method instead of a function, I had to use the out argument modifier and I also had to initialize the property value with default(T) which of course, negates what I am trying to do.  I think the above will work, I was just wondering if there was a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `ref` keyword:

```
private T SetPropertyValue<T>(ref T property, T value)
{
    if (!EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(property, value))
    {
        if (!IsInitializing)
        {
            IsDirty = true;
        }
        property = value;
    }
}

public DateTimeOffset? ActualProjectCompletionDate
{
    get { return _actualProjectCompletionDate; }
    set { SetPropertyValue(ref _actualProjectCompletionDate, value); }
}
```